# Autolayout of custom UITableViewCell finds conflicting constraints in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I encountered the following problem. I was designing a custom UITableViewCell Design with Autolayout and everything worked perfectly. **Xcode is not showing me any errors.**

But when I do run the app on the simulator or an actual iPhone, I get the following error code in the console:

```
2020-04-16 17:14:36.928201+0200 Promille[11911:1025126] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000ddc460 UIStackView:0x7f8bba72bb20.height == 75   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000ddc7d0 V:[UIStackView:0x7f8bba72bb20]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8bba712390 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000ddc870 V:|-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7f8bba72bb20]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8bba712390 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000dde0d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8bba712390.height == 95.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000ddc460 UIStackView:0x7f8bba72bb20.height == 75   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

*The error is associated with the height, because as soon as I delete the height constraint everything works perfectly. However in this case both images are full size and the TableViewCell height is more than 1000px.*

**Here is also an image of the .xib file:**
[image]

***The really weird thing is that I do not change any constraints at runtime. Only the text labels are changed. So how can it be that auto layout finds an error, that auto layout didn't find while designing the layout?***

---

And do you have any idea what the last constraint in the error message is about, because I didn't set the height of the content view.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000dde0d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8bba712390.height == 95.5   (active)>"
```

Hope you guys can think of a reason / solution for this problem to appear.

Comment: A little confusing... do you **want** your Height constraint of 75? Or do you want the height to be based on the size of the cell content? i.e. might *"Neuer Benutzer"* label need to wrap onto multiple lines?

Comment: @DonMag yes. the content's height should always be 75px and all labels have exactly one line (+ auto shrink)

Comment: It seems to be a common issue. While the constraints *may* be correct, auto-layout generates that warning while making adjustments to the cell height. Changing the `Priority` of your stack view's Height constraint to `999` should resolve the issue.

Comment: @DonMag thanks. That Did work! Was working on this for quiet a long time and this was so easy;) Thank you.

Comment: I added this as an answer... you can mark it accepted for the benefit of other folks who come across the same (or similar) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a common issue.

While the constraints may be correct, auto-layout generates that warning while making adjustments to the cell height.

Changing the Priority of your stack view's Height constraint to 999 should resolve the issue.

---

**Edit**

Here is an example - layout should be close to what you've shown.

I gave each image view a width of 30 and 1:1 ratio.

I gave the "Outer" stack view a height constraint of 75, but note that instead of setting its priority to 999, I set its bottom constraint to **greater than or equal** to 8. That also eliminates the run-time layout issues, and also lets me work on the cell design without having to worry about Interface Builder complaining about the cell height.

So, at run-time, the actual cell height will be 75 plus 8-pts top and bottom "padding."

[image]

and here's how it looks at run-time:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
class RegistrationCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblAge: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblGender: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblWeight: UILabel!

}

struct Benutzer {
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var gender: Int = 0
    var weight: Float = 0.0
}

class RegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myData: [Benutzer] = [
        Benutzer(name: "Christian", age: 24, gender: 0, weight: 81.0),
        Benutzer(name: "Tobias", age: 25, gender: 0, weight: 83.5),
        Benutzer(name: "Astrid", age: 22, gender: 1, weight: 50.0),
        Benutzer(name: "Frank", age: 26, gender: 0, weight: 82.0),
        Benutzer(name: "Birgit", age: 21, gender: 1, weight: 49.5),
        Benutzer(name: "Petra", age: 23, gender: 1, weight: 48.0),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RegistrationCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RegistrationCell

        let d = myData[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblName.text = d.name
        cell.lblAge.text = "\(d.age)"
        cell.lblGender.text = d.gender == 0 ? "M" : "F"
        cell.lblWeight.text = "\(d.weight)"

        return cell
    }

}
```

and here's the source for my `RegistrationCell.xib` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15705" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15706"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="123" id="7Ao-kn-tXV" customClass="RegistrationCell" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="123"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="7Ao-kn-tXV" id="47R-qN-jmt">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="123"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="w3y-Sd-Nos" userLabel="OuterStack">
                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="398" height="75"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wyp-v1-tmD" userLabel="NameStack">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="398" height="37.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="person" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Fjj-yM-fPo" userLabel="img Profile Image">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="5.5" width="30" height="27.5"/>
                                        <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="30" id="GMk-hN-m2Y"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Fjj-yM-fPo" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="twh-eK-7fi"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </imageView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Neuer Benutzer" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7L6-cN-3lF">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="42" y="5.5" width="314" height="26.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="semibold" pointSize="22"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="checkmark.seal.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2LH-yE-mwq" userLabel="img Active">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="368" y="3.5" width="30" height="31.5"/>
                                        <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="30" id="Ar9-oX-QRg"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="2LH-yE-mwq" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="iIC-xx-qUj"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </imageView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="23" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="moe-fr-waY" userLabel="LowerStack">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="37.5" width="398" height="37.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="p9M-2u-yIn" userLabel="AgeStack">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="117.5" height="37.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="calendar" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JLv-Bq-0aO">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="5" width="30" height="27.5"/>
                                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="30" id="329-R5-jp7"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="JLv-Bq-0aO" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="FCZ-nk-tMN"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WG8-WN-s2X">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="8.5" width="75.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tfc-eV-c24" userLabel="GenderStack">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="140.5" y="0.0" width="117" height="37.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="person.2.square.stack.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VQ9-tf-mkF">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="3" width="30" height="31.5"/>
                                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="30" id="1xw-b0-vZp"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="VQ9-tf-mkF" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="zmL-Jl-F55"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tg8-Bx-TWD">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="8.5" width="75" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9bU-4J-00h" userLabel="WeightStack">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="280.5" y="0.0" width="117.5" height="37.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="gauge" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uXN-UL-NhM">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="4.5" width="30" height="29"/>
                                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="30" id="3dU-2L-zOp"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="uXN-UL-NhM" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="xI1-Qm-Vr5"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Wwy-kf-N2Z">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="42" y="8.5" width="75.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="75" id="jPs-ix-1GZ"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </stackView>
                </subviews>
                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99996358159999998" green="0.77101260419999995" blue="0.16773471240000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="w3y-Sd-Nos" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="47R-qN-jmt" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="ba9-oa-K7s"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="w3y-Sd-Nos" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="47R-qN-jmt" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="hO0-zC-Vbj"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="w3y-Sd-Nos" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="s1f-TA-lYa"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="w3y-Sd-Nos" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="ypb-vP-adn"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="lblAge" destination="WG8-WN-s2X" id="WBO-bZ-8SE"/>
                <outlet property="lblGender" destination="tg8-Bx-TWD" id="bTQ-bI-zSz"/>
                <outlet property="lblName" destination="7L6-cN-3lF" id="scr-s2-IiF"/>
                <outlet property="lblWeight" destination="Wwy-kf-N2Z" id="3pY-yL-8Ys"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-252.17391304347828" y="53.236607142857139"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="calendar" catalog="system" width="64" height="52"/>
        <image name="checkmark.seal.fill" catalog="system" width="64" height="60"/>
        <image name="gauge" catalog="system" width="64" height="60"/>
        <image name="person" catalog="system" width="64" height="58"/>
        <image name="person.2.square.stack.fill" catalog="system" width="56" height="64"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. However, is there any way to set the cellView height to priority to 999 since the Stack Views height is the height I want for my UITableViewCell?

Comment: @Chri2000R - I edited my answer with example code for you to examine.

Comment: Indeed lowering the priority either of the height or the bottom constraint to the content view solved it. It seems Autolayout tries to first layout the view as if the cell has a fixed size (which raises the warning). Then resizes the cell

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer, but a bone-headed mistake that led me here. I had a vertical stackview that was supposedly breaking constraints. What I didn't realize for the longest time was that the stackview had it's bottom anchor constrained to the `bottomAnchor` of the actually `UITableViewCell` object itself, not its `contentView`.

Answer (score -1):

You can constraint everything against the cell in the storyboard as this [image: image shows].

Then you can set the height of the tableviewcell in this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75
}
```

Then you do not need to set the height of the cell in the storyboard. You could also use a dynamic height here, for example, to make it the half of the size of the whole screen.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.view.bounds.height / 0.5
}
```

To add this method you need to conform to

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

The tableviewdelegate do you not need for this but add it for other tableviewmethods. Do not forget to set the delegate

```
tableview.delegate = self
```

Comment: While implementing `heightForRowAt` *may* solve this specific issue, it's generally a bad idea. If different cell classes / content / heights are needed, `heightForRowAt` tends to end up with a bunch of if/else or switch cases. If the cell changes at some point, then you also have to remember to change values in `heightForRowAt`. Much better to allow auto-layout to do the work.